# visibility: hidden / 'visiblity': 'visible' = not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to hide the script the photoset until it has been completed, however the following code doesn't seem to work:

**jQuery**

```
$('.photoset-grid').photosetGrid({
rel: $('.photoset-grid').attr("data-id"),
gutter: '0px',

onComplete: function(){

    $('.photoset-grid').css({
        'visiblity': 'visible'
    });
}
});
```

**HTML**

```
{block:Photoset}
<div class="photoset-grid" data-layout="{PhotosetLayout}" data-id="photoset{PostID}" style="visibility: hidden;" />
  {block:Photos}
  <img src="{PhotoURL-500}"
  {block:HighRes}data-highres="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"{/block:HighRes}
  width="{PhotoWidth-500}" height="{PhotoHeight-500}"
  {block:Caption}alt="{Caption}"{/block:caption} />
  {/block:Photos}
</div><!-- /.tumblr-photoset -->

{block:Caption}<div class="photoset-grid-copy">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
{/block:Photoset}
```

Comment: And which problem are you facing with your code?

Comment: well, you have "'visiblity': 'visible'". this should be "'visibility': 'visible'"

Answer (score 2):

Use display: hidden and display:block;

or in jquery $('.photoset-grid').show() and $('.photoset-grid').hide()

```
http://api.jquery.com/show/
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, `visibility` is spelled incorrectly:

```
$('.photoset-grid').photosetGrid({
  rel: $('.photoset-grid').attr("data-id"),
  gutter: '0px',
  onComplete: function(){

    $('.photoset-grid').css({
        'visibility': 'visible'
    });
  }
});
```